# contexts for copy and paste in eclipse for own plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to use copy and paste within my own view. Therefore I defined commands with a special context and activated it during the creation of the view.
The problem I'm now facing is that copy and paste is workin within my view but no longer within the normal eclipse world.
The context has a parent id into org.eclipse.ui.window.

Any hints how to seperate these contexs right so corresponding action is called at the right time.
I also turned on the key bind tracing within the debug options of org.eclipse.ui.

basic idea: How to override an existing key binding?

http://rcpexperiments.blogspot.de/2009/07/commands-key-bindings-and-contexts-in.html

key tracing: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/07/08/tip-tracing-keybindings-in-rcp/

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to use a context. You just provide an action handler for the global copy / paste actions:

```java
   IActionBars actionBars = getViewSite().getActionBars();

   actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.COPY.getId(), copyAction);

   actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.PASTE.getId(), pasteAction);
```

Comment: by doing so, where do I have to define the key binds or are they inherited from the global copy action, and how would I connect the action with my CopyHandler (AbstractHandler)

Comment: You have to use the old style `Action` to hook in to these and don't use a handler. The key binding is already defined in Eclipse. This is all based on `RetargetAction`

Comment: thx, I guess that could work, but I would lose the ability to edit the visibility used within the command definition in the plugin.xml